# UIButton setting .isEnabled causes Thread 1 Fatal Error (Finding nil when unwraping an optional)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After updating to Xcode 10.1, I've had some problems with a UIButton connection.

I declare the button as so (and set it weak despite Xcode 10.1 auto declaration to not)

```
@IBOutlet weak var nextBtn: UIButton!
```

I call the button in the follow function and the error (Thread 1 Fatal Error) is thrown on the line nextBtn.isEnabled = false

```
@IBAction func record(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == "Record"{
        setupRecorder()
        soundRecorder.deleteRecording()
        soundRecorder.record()
        sender.setTitle("Stop", for : .normal)
        playBtn.isEnabled = false
        nextBtn.isEnabled = false
    }else{
        soundRecorder.stop()
        sender.setTitle("Record", for : .normal)
        playBtn.isEnabled = false
    }
```

Here is a picture of the outlet connections for the button:

[image: Here is a picture of the outlet connections for the button]

As you can see, it appears to be properly referenced and it does perform the necessary action when clicked on to go to the next screen.

I have also attached a picture of all the outlets connected to the screen.

[image: Record Screen outlets]

**What I have tried so far**

- Cleaning project folder
- Restarting Xcode/computer
- Deleting DerivedData and proceeding to clean project folder
- Renaming variable name
- Reconnecting the outlet from the storyboard

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried adding new buttons to see if the problem was universal. When I had done so, the buttons did not appear in the simulator (but they are on the storyboard). Any suggestions?

Comment: You may check if the xib file or storyboard file's checkbox for your current running target is selected or not.

Comment: Is your button added as subview in xib? 
If not, than it's possible it is deallocated because it's reference count is 0. Try to remove 'weak' from your first line.

Comment: @Surely The running target is properly selected, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @IvoLeko tried removing weak, still didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @JDog it would be good for you to provide us more details, like more source code where 'nextBtn' is used, .xib structure and more details about crash error.

Comment: @IvoLeko nextBtn isn't used anywhere else, and the crash error is thrown where .isEnabled is used (fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)

Comment: Seems you have record screen and record screen2. Without having access to code sample, it’d be hard to tell where the reference is broken, but moost likely the nextBtn isn’t connected to xib/storyboard correctly.